# How to create interactive plot of thousands of images as output of t-SNE?

Tags: python, visualization, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I have many images that I want to plot as a result of running t-SNE and I want to be able to interactively explore them.  matplotlib does not allow enough interactivity to explore, and plotly is [too slow](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/978).

Is there an easy way to plot thousands of images in a way that different patterns can be explored?

Comment: Checkout the below link to github which takes a set of images and clusters them using k-means and maps it to 3-D points using UMAP or t-sne and puts it in a 3-D interactive webGL page. https://github.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/

Answer (score 7):

It is certainly possible to create interactive plots of many thousands of images, as Google has done in their interactive [art t-SNE Map](https://artsexperiments.withgoogle.com/tsnemap/).

However, as far as I have found, there is not any canned way to do this.  https://github.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot is an open source application that also does an impressive job at plotting thousands of images, and if you are using python (e.g. with scikit-learn's t-SNE), it does not look too bad to modify to your use case.

Answer (score 7):

[Datashader](http://datashader.org/) is a Python visualization library designed to handle large datasets. A tutorial to plot t-SNE with datashader can be found [here](https://jlorince.github.io/viz-tutorial/).